# how to save select option value in database on cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I wanna save a selected option in database in cakephp.
here is my add.ctp code

```
<?php
      $options = array('0' => 'male', '1' => 'female');
      echo $this->Form->select('gender', $options, array('escape' => false,'id'=>'gender'));
  ?>
```

and this is my action :

```
     $user=$this->Users->newEntity();
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        print_r($user);
        $this->Users->save($user);
       }
```

But when I run it just the value 1 saved on database even I choose male.
please help.

Comment: Where are your debugging results? What does `print_r($user)` show (btw you better use `debug($user)`). What does the request data look like? Is the value already always `1` _before_ saving? Of what type is the database column? Please **[edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38540607/edit)** and add more info so that the problem becomes reproducible.

Comment: thank you your comment helps me on solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The type of gender on database was bit I changed it to INT and every thing works correctly.